# smarty dynamic variable names access

Tags: variables, dynamic, smarty

I want to iterate through different variables that have a number suffix. Is there a way to iterater through them dynamically?

Let's say I have variables 
`$sArticle.attr1, $sArticle.attr2 ... $sArticle.attr7`

How can I iterate through all attr* variables dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{for}` and create a variable containing the name, then using that variable as the index:

```
{for $foo=1 to 7}
    {$attr_index='attr'|cat:$foo}
    <p>{$sArticle.$attr_index}</p>
{/for}
```